# Expanding the MySQL Database Size

Tags: mysql

We are planning to Expand our Database from 1 Tb to 2 Tb. what must be the corresponding configurations of  the CPU and RAM  for this.

Comment: Have you read the installation guide?  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/5.7/en/

Comment: @GerardH.Pille sir please provide the neccessory configurations ..

Comment: Size of your database does not directly correlate to CPU and RAM, so I don't think anyone can provide you an answer. More important factors to this question is your current workload, the use cases that create that workload, and metrics on how much utilization those hardware components are typically under. Long story short, only you would know if you need to increase the CPU and RAM by monitoring, measuring, and comparing after the change.

Comment: @J.D. Thanks for your suggestion, we want to increase our CPU currently we are using  8 Core - 16 Thread CPU and want to upgrade to    24 core - 64 Thread CPU what steps must be taken and what should be our configurations according to this.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Thanks Gerald , we want to increase our CPU currently we are using 8 Core - 16 Thread CPU and want to upgrade to 24 core - 64 Thread CPU what steps must be taken and what should be our configurations according to this

Comment: There is no relation between database size, database configuration, CPU and memory.  Depending on the quality of the database and application design, more or less CPU and memory is needed.  I would advise you to find a trustworthy consultant - which can also be very hard.

Answer (score 1):

It is a rare MySQL server that needs to increase CPU.  What is the "load average" now (typically)?  How many Cores are you using now?  If you are running out of cores now, then I would strongly encourage you to look into optimizing the slowest queries.  That is more likely to be beneficial than adding more cores.

Increasing RAM may or may not be necessary as the disk footprint increases.  It mostly depends on the "working set".  This is a nebulous concept; there is no good way to measure it.

If you are doing a lot of table scans, again I say that working on the query and/or indexes is the way to go.  That will help I/O, RAM, and CPU.  At some RAM threshold, the I/O (and elapsed time) for a query will jump.  Fix the query, if possible, rather than throwing hardware at it.

A common source of table scans is summarizing "data warehouse" type data.  That can be very efficiently remedied (CPU, RAM, and IOPS) by building and maintaining a "summary table".  (Ask for help if relevant.)

If you have years worth of data, but you only look at "recent" data (*and use a suitable Where clause*), then the working set is probably very small, and increasing RAM is a waste of money.

Primary settings to change:

- When changing the disk from HDD to SSD, some settings should be changed.
- When enlarging the disk, no settings need be changed.  (Ask if relevant.)
- When increasing RAM, the main change to make is increasing `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 70% of RAM.  (We need a lot more details to help with any less-important settings.)
- When increasing the number of cores, no settings need to change.

Further steps:

- For a review of what you have *now*, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis
- For huge databases, it is wise to review the schema with an eye to how the disk size can be shrunk.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/schema_best_practices_mysql